# Python newbie exercise: Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to code a simple game of RPS where the user plays against the computer.
There's just 1 iteration at this point (because I got stuck...) and no validation whether the user's input is valid.
The problem I got stuck with is that whatever I tried to do in order to get the computer's and the user's score stored in a variable, it they kept being equal to 0, no matter what indentation I tried or wherever I tried to place the return. (as you could see in my code below... some parts that I tried with no luck are commented out). Ideally, since I plan on multiple iterations, I'd like the variables u and v themselves to be updated and keep score, not just print who won the specific iteration.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers

```
from random import randrange
rps = ["r", "p", "s"]



def gameplay(user,comp):
    u = 0 #user's score
    v = 0 #computer's score
    print "Computer chose: " + comp
    if comp == user:
        pass
    elif comp == "r" and user == "p":
        u += 1
        #print u
        #return u

    elif comp == "r" and user == "s":
        v += 1
        #print v
        #return v

    elif comp == "p" and user == "s":
        u += 1
        #print u
        #return u

    elif comp == "p" and user == "r":
        v += 1
        #print v
        #return v

    elif comp == "s" and user == "r":
        u += 1
        #print u
        #return u

    elif comp == "s" and user == "p":
        v += 1
        #print v
        #return v

    return u
    return v

gameplay(raw_input("your move?"),rps[randrange(3)])
print u
print v
```

Comment: try `return u, v` and `u, v = gameplay(...)`

Comment: When a function hits a return value, the function is done, so you'll never return v. You can return them both in one statement, return (u, v). The return value must be stored in a variable afterwards: u, v = gameplay(...)

Answer (score 3):

just for fun ... see if you can understand this OOP implementation (its never too early to start learning OOP)

```
WIN,TIE,LOSE = 1,0,-1
class RockPaperScissors:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
class Rock(RockPaperScissors):
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,Rock): return TIE
        if isinstance(other,Paper): return LOSE
        return WIN

class Paper(RockPaperScissors):
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,Paper): return TIE
        if isinstance(other,Scissors):return LOSE
        return WIN

class Scissors(RockPaperScissors):
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,Scissors): return TIE
        if isinstance(other,Rock):return LOSE
        return WIN

def RPS(ltr_code):
    return {'r':Rock,'p':Paper,'s':Scissors}[ltr_code.lower()]()


player = RPS("r")
computer = RPS("s")
if player > computer:
    print "Player Wins! %s beats %s"%(player,computer)
elif player < computer:
    print "Computer wins!! %s beats %s"%(computer,player)
else: 
    print "Tied!! %s ties %s"%(computer,player)
```

Comment: spoiler: nope. :) Haven't learnt __str__, __cmp__ yet. Thanks though - will get back to it

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your program:

1. A function can return multiple values, but it has to return them as a tuple, not first the one, then the other. Change the return statement to `return (u, v)`
2. You need to bind the values returned by the function to some values outside of the function so you can use them. Try `u, v = gameplay(...)`. This will bind the values of `u` and `v` returned from the function to the variables `u` and `v` outside of the function. The names of the variables do not have to match; you can use any other name, as well, like `my_score, cpu_score = gameplay(...)`

When those two are fixed, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call "gameplay" at the beginning you are setting u, v = 0, 0. You need to define the scores outside the method to make everything work fine:

```
from random import randrange
rps = ["r", "p", "s"]

u, v = 0, 0

def gameplay(user,comp,u,v):
    print "Computer chose: " + comp
    if comp == user:
        pass
    elif comp == "r" and user == "p":
        u += 1
    elif comp == "r" and user == "s":
        v += 1
    elif comp == "p" and user == "s":
        u += 1
    elif comp == "p" and user == "r":
        v += 1
    elif comp == "s" and user == "r":
        u += 1
    elif comp == "s" and user == "p":
        v += 1
    return u, v

for i in range(4): # 4 Games
    u, v = gameplay(raw_input("your move?"),rps[randrange(3)],u,v)

print "User: ", u, " CPU: ",v #Displaying final scores
```

Comment: thanks for this. when I tried to take u, v outside the function the interpreter produce an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'u' referenced before assignment

Comment: EDIT: ok, I see what you did there. I tried adding 
while u < 2 and v < 2:
    u_score, v_score = gameplay(raw_input("your move?"),rps[randrange(3)],u,v)
else:
    "game over"

after the function but it won't 'keep score'

Comment: That its produced because in "gameplay" you are not defining any (u,v) thats why i my answer (u,v) are parameters so the method can know what they are and use them correctly. ;)

Comment: You mean something like this? : while u<2 and v<2:
    u, v = gameplay(raw_input("your move?"),rps[randrange(3)],u,v)

if(u==2):
 print "You won!"
else:
 print "GAMEOVER"

print "User: ", u, " CPU: ",v #Displaying final scores. You changed  u,v to u_score, v_score. They need to keep the same name, because they are reutilized by gameplay(...,u,v) and thats the part that keeps the score.

Comment: If you think my aswer was correct set it as the correct answer of your question ! :)